# Set locale/region while crawling

Tags: selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl information from [this](http://www.phiverivers.com/womens/buy-women-tan-genuine-leather-satchelbag-PR1064) website on an AWS machine. The machine, being hosted in US, gives me the price of the product in USD. How can I get the price in INR - the way I see it when I crawl on my  local machine.

I normally use Scrapy to crawl the information but am open to using Selenium or any other tool for the same.

I tried using selenium and setting the browser locale to "en-IN" but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use TOR (you can setup proxy in Selenium and select desired output node in TOR).
Changing locale can help in some cases only because it's more likely that site is tracking your IP